# PHP IMAP Connect Issue

Tags: php

I have configured Gmail account via PHP IMAP to read mailbox. It was working fine, but suddenly it has stopped and I am getting following error:

> [PhpImap\ConnectionException]
>     Connection error: Can not authenticate to IMAP server: [ALERT] Please log in via your web browser: https://support.google.com/mail/acc

I have enabled less secure account too, but it didn't work.

Comment: Maybe try this https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also faced this issue few days before and by these steps my issue was resolved.

- Head over to Account Security Settings (https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) and enable "Access for less secure apps", this allows you to use the google smtp for clients other than the official ones.
- Visit http://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha and sign in with your Gmail username and password.
- Your app might not support the latest security standards. Try changing a few settings to allow less secure apps access to your account.
- Make sure your mail app isn't set to check for new email too often. If your mail app checks for new messages more than once every 10
  minutes, the app’s access to your account could be blocked.

I think this may help you.